# Twitter API get list hashtag by keyword

Tags: api, twitter, hashtag

I want to retrieve keyword **hashtags** using the Twitter API.

example:

[image]

I use the API `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23a` but it is not the result I expected

Comment: Did you authenticate before this request?

Comment: @ZavenZareyan Yes, I'm. I mean, I want to get the hashtag list by keyword, but the api search returns the hashtag tweet list.